# Bring toolbar to the front of page in Angular/HTML?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to bring the toolbar to the front of the page, so that when I scroll down on the page, the elements on the page do not cover the toolbar. However, as of now, the elements on the page are doing just that.

Here is the CSS for the toolbar:

```
.maintoolbar.mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Z-index does not seem to be doing anything. Is there a better way to bring the toolbar to the front so that scrolling down does not cause the toolbar to be covered by other elements on the page?

Answer (score 1):

It may be as simple as changing the z-index of your "position" styled classes to "1" -> "z-index: 1" as "-1" places the referenced elements more inward on the page/behind other elements.

Edit: Ha, answered your own question the same time I answered, good on ya for figuring it out.

- Drew

Answer (score 0):

Z-index has to be a higher number than the items you want it to be in front of, not lower.